# How to remove duplicate product images in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I import product from CSV file. After import success, I check the product detail. The product images are duplicated.

[image]

How to fix it?

How to create a script to find all product images duplicated to delete?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Comment: Apparently its a bug and still havent been resolved - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21885, https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/26713

Comment: Hi Kalvin Klien, I did that but it didn't resolve my issue. I am using Magento 2.3.4